# Notation for base change $X_K$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme/variety over $k$ and $K/k$ a field extension. I found the notation  $X \otimes_k K$ (see for example chapter 1 in "Period Spaces for p-divisible groups" by Rapoport and Zink) and was wondering if this is just a(n) (old) notation for the base change $X_K$ or anything else?

Comment: Yes, it's just the base change. Note that this notation is also still used sometimes

Comment: @Notone that looks like an answer to me - would you care to record it as such below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is just the base change. This notation is also still used sometimes